# How to kill chrome driver tasks after every instance execution in karate framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, karate

I have executed 61 tests with 4 instances at 3 times It got passed. After I have executed 4th time my browser was launched but not redirected to URL. I got stopped due to the old chrome driver instance persisting in the task manager. Could you help with that how to kill by automation script

Comment: I have nothing to add to this answer to be honest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66828432/143475 - also do a search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+kill+process

Comment: @PeterThomas I have noticed that if driver is used within a call from karate-config.js as part of background, a manual driver.quit() call is necessary or else it does not quit. Thus if something fails and it does not get to the driver.quit() call an instance will remain open in the background. I haven't done a full investigation, but maybe this information is useful.