# Deleting Target folder from Karate project for UI automation stopped running feature files via TestRunner.java

Tags: karate

I created 3 simple feature files for Karate UI automation to be executed on chrome browser. Executing these feature files via TestRunner.java created multiple chrome subfolders under 'target' folder for every execution.
I deleted the target folder assuming that it will be re-created for the new test run but TestRunner.java has stopped executing the feature files now. It shows Runs:0/0  Errors:0 Failures:0

Answer (score 0):

Look for chrome processes that are running and kill them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66828432/143475

Note that it is possible to set the chrome working directory if you really want to, search for `userDataDir` in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver