# Not able to launch edge browse when created job in Jenkins which is running in server

Tags: karate

I created simple test to launch edge browser using karate test automation and created a job in Jenkins which is running in server ,when I build the job getting error saying karate.karateexception start failed

Am able launch edge browser in my local machine

Comment: yes, running the browser in the cloud is not easy. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325328/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter for quick reply provided reference not able get how to proceed like what I need to add/configure first to run simple test to launch edgedriver on cloud machine

Comment: use docker. or a headless browser. now read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#dockertarget