# waitForUrl() getting failed, while running features in parallel

Tags: karate

I am implementing karate test for UI-application.
Running the feature files through a single thread got succeded. While running the feature files in parallel, waitForUrl() is getting failed.

I am getting an exception like (org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: waitForUrl: failed after 3 retries and 9066 milliseconds) while running feature files in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to UI tests, running them in parallel requires careful consideration. You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325328/143475

Since the problem you are referring to has never been reported before, please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue